# Forcing Tesseract to give some answer

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to recognize one line of handwritten digits. Currently I do some preprocessing with Python and OpenCV, split the image into connected components and feed these components to Tesseract with PSM=10 (page segmentation mode, 10 is "treat the image like a single character") and character whitelist restricted to "0123456789". I expect Tesseract to return garbage where my connected component segmentation fails and to return exactly one digit when my segmentation succeeds. Tesseract often returns nothing at all.

I have tried both [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) and [python-tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/) as a Tesseract interface for Python. Pytesseract works by locating the executable `tesseract.exe`, running it with suitable parameters from the shell and collecting the answer. This is how I found out about my problem. After that, I tried python-tesseract, which implements a full-blown C API. Naturally, the result was the same.

Below is a sample of 5 images I fed into Tesseract separately (I've also uploaded the same images as separate files [here](https://app.box.com/s/b259k7qvoektkcv8pm9q)):

[image: images sample]

I get 1,*,4,*,* on these images, * meaning that Tesseract returned only whitespace.

With other page segmentation modes, I get the following:

```
PSM_SINGLE_CHAR: 1*4**
PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK_VERT_TEXT: **43*
PSM_CIRCLE_WORD: 11***
PSM_SINGLE_LINE: 11491
PSM_AUTO: *****
PSM_SPARSE_TEXT: *****
PSM_SINGLE_WORD: 11499
PSM_AUTO_ONLY: *****
PSM_SINGLE_COLUMN: *****
PSM_SPARSE_TEXT_OS: *****
PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK: 11499
PSM_OSD_ONLY: *****
PSM_AUTO_OSD: *****
PSM_COUNT: 11499
```

Weirdly, when I run `tesseract image.png image -l eng -psm 10 digits-only` against these images, it returns *,*,4,9,*. (`digits-only` is `tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789`)

How do I force Tesseract to give me some answer instead of nothing at all?

Comment: Which version of tesseract are you using? Can you show examples for images? Do you have the same result for a run without psm 10?

Comment: @tobltobs, thank you for answering. I don't know for sure which version of Tesseract I am using, since python-tesseract seems to come with pre-packaged Tesseract. However, I assume that since Tesseract was last updated in 2012 and python-tesseract was last updated in Aug 2014, I am using v3.02. My tessdata comes from an 'official' installation, though. I have also added some images to the post.

Comment: I don't know about any software which would be able to read the above images as numbers. I can only decipher the last two myself.

Comment: @tobltobs, I was hoping that Tesseract implemented something akin to the winners of [the MNIST challenge](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Those algorithms are capable of deciphering images like the ones I provided.