# What is the easiest way to obtain a state-of-the-art handwritten digit classifier?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, caffe

I am working on a project involving OCR-ing handwritten digits which uses a typical preprocessing-segmentation-recognition pipeline. I have done the first two stages manually by adjusting some standard algorithms from `OpenCV` for my particular task. For the third stage (recognition), I'd like to use a ready-made classifier.

First I tried Tesseract, but it was [really bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321553/forcing-tesseract-to-give-some-answer). So I started looking into the progress on `MNIST`. Due to its popularity, I'd hoped it would be easy to get a nice high-quality classifier. Indeed, the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319730/suggestions-for-digit-recognition) suggests using a `HOG+SVM` tandem, which is conveniently implemented in [this `OpenCV` sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/digits.py). Unfortunately, it isn't as good as I'd hoped. It keeps confusing `0`'s for `8`'s (where it is obvious for my eye that it is actually a `0`), which accounts by far for the greatest amount of mistakes my algorithm makes.

Here are some examples of the errors made by `HOG+SVM`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The top line are the original digits extracted from the image (higher-resolution images do not exist), the middle line are these digits deskewed, size-normalized and centered, and the bottom line is the output of `HOG+SVM`.

I tried to hot-fix this `0-8` error by applying a `kNN` classifier after `HOG+SVM` (if `HOG+SVM` outputs an `8` run `kNN` and return its output instead), but the results were the same.

Then I tried to adapt [this `pylearn2` sample](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/tree/master/pylearn2/scripts/papers/maxout) which claims to achieve 0.45% `MNIST` test error. However, after spending a week with `pylearn2` I couldn't make it work. It [keeps crashing randomly all the time](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylearn-users/WLm8pZ2Vb0M), even in an environment as sterile as an `Amazon EC2` `g2.2xlarge` instance running [this image](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-735bda04--ubuntu14-04-mkl-cuda-dl) (I don't even mention my own machine).

I know about the existence of `Caffe`, but I haven't tried it.

What would be the easiest way to set up a high-accuracy (say, MNIST test error <1%) handwritten digit classifier? Preferably, one that does not require an `NVIDIA` card to run. As far as I understand, `pylearn2` (since it heavily relies on `cuda-convnet`) does. A `Python` interface and an ability to run on `Windows` would be a pleasant bonus.

Note: I cannot create a new `pylearn2` tag since I don't have enough reputation, but it surely should be there.

Answer (score 2):

In the webpage of the MINST database you can find at the bottom a benchmark of the state of the art methods with links to their papers:

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

The last entry of the table has the best result with a 0.23% of error (pretty impressive).

Short answer: there is no `easy` way to achieve state of the art rate, unless you can accept some 2-5% of error (then use sklearn) or you find the code online.

Comment: Of course I know about them. Problem is, the top result uses (it seems) a fork of `cuda-convnet`, which is close to impossible to compile. And the others close to the top are only papers. I am asking for a solution that I can compile and run. As I said, `pylearn2` claims to achieve 0.45%, but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error rate that is acceptable for you? I can suggest you some approaches depending on your error threshold.

Comment: According to a crude estimation, <1% would be ideal, <2% would be acceptable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and try caffe if you haven't done it already. 
It is much easier than cuda-convnet to compile, it does not rely on cuda (although it speeds up things considerably) and it has an example for mnist with the Lenet algorithm.

look here:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/dev/examples/mnist